# In Javascript, how to get the current id of the div where mouse pointer is?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mouseover

How to get the id of the div on which the mouse is currently pointing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your best bet is to track `mouseover` at the `document` level and maintain the id of the last element hit.

```
var lastID = null;

var handleMouseover = function (e) {
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    lastID = target.id;
};

if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener('mouseover', handleMouseover, false);
}
else {
    document.attachEvent('onmouseover', handleMouseover);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="the-id" onmouseover="alert(this.id)">some text</div>
```

Comment: @Downvoters: What's wrong with my answer? Not for the two -1 (don't care) but for the way i solved the problem.

Comment: no vote from me, but you'd have to do that on every element if you want to determine which one you are currently over.

Comment: Of course, yes, but the op did not specify he wanted something like that. Btw i've understood, thanks. ;)

Comment: its simple i can limit it to which divs I want! thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a javascript variable to store the current hovered div..  jQuery (or standard JS) could be used to set the event handler to populate the variable.

Visible test at: http://jsfiddle.net/gfosco/Hys7r/